# load website with hashs in the url

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I've got a webview that I save the url from anytime the application goes to the background/exits so I can preserve our users location on our website.

I store user-entered data in hashtags in the url:

```
https://test.org/?page=test#user_dat1=test#user_dat2=test
```

Where user_dat1 and user_dat2 is keeping track of where the user is and what they have entered on a page.

When I use the following:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://test.org/?page=test#user_dat1=test#user_dat2=test"];
[self.mywebview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

I get this out:

```
https://test.org/?page=test%23user_dat1=test%23user_dat2=test
```

Which crashes both my php and js.

How can I force hashtags to not be encoded?

EDIT: 
**Code solution I made with guidance from marked solution**

```
function read_hashes(){
    try { // I know I shouldn't use try... but this is a easy way to reject invalid hashes
        var hashes = window.location.hash;
        hashes = hashes.substring(1);
        hashes = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(hashes));
        if (hashes["user_dat1"] != null){//check if var is in json hash
            //do what you need to do with this var.
        }
        ...
    } catch(err){}

}
function put_hashes(){
    var hashes = {};
    hashes["user_dat1"] = "test data";
    hashes = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(hashes));
    window.location.hash ="#" + hashes;
}
```

This allows me to store variables in a js hash to keep user data in a form. And just a note, I know this is a security issue, I don't use this on any page that this would result in a security issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not with NSURL -- this is an invalid url if it wasn't encoded.

`NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://test.org/?page=test#user_dat1=test#user_dat2=test"];` returns nil ==> showing you the string is **not** a valid url

to re-iterate: invalid urls are just not possible with NSURL Loading System.

---

what makes it invalid are the two hashes. Encode 1 then fix your decoding and send `test.org/?page=test#user_dat1=test%23user_dat2=test`

---

the op only wants the fragment inside his local JS it turned out. So Id suggest fixing the encoding locally

Comment: Then how would I go about loading that url into my webview?

Comment: not at all. the url is invalid. fix the server.. according to the rfc it isn't ok :) [or you encode it]

Comment: Everything after the first # are only used by the client side javascript. It's only rejected by the server if you encode the # because the it becomes part of the php get variables

Comment: yes, that doesn't change the fact that the url isn't valid. that your server implementation works and doesn't require encoding...... 'fortunate'

Comment: Anything after the # isn't even sent to the server, how would I preserve the javascript hash? Reference here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp

Comment: then fix your local JS to reverse the decoding and send 'https://test.org/?page=test#user_dat1=test%23user_dat2=test

Comment: or use `stringByEvaluatingJavascript` to pass in an arbitrary string to JS

Comment: So the problem is the 2 hashes? I can fix that. Thanks. I'll try it in the morning :)