# opening a received url with safari

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am receiving a url from a server request, I made a button , when pressed, safari must open and go to the link,
My code below:

```
- (IBAction)openFeedbackWebViewPresser:(id)sender {
    NSString *feedbackUrl = self.getConfig.feedbackURL;   
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: feedbackUrl]];

}
```

If I print the feedback url , its as below:

```
https://xxx.xxxxx.com/CRM/feedback#/1715171559ae979371687#/10306
```

I tried to use another way:

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:feedbackUrl];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: url];
```

the url is returning nil, knowing that the feedbackUrl contains a url.
Any idea whats wrong?
Thanks

Comment: and what happens?

Comment: nothing, just nothing is opening or happening.

Comment: check whether your url contains any spaces

Comment: did checked, no spaces, even I copied the url into safari on the Mac, it opened normally

Comment: Your URL isn't valid because of the hashes. If encoding them doesn't work you need to fix your server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [load website with hashs in the url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37369024/load-website-with-hashs-in-the-url)

Comment: and how do I encode it?

Comment: @Ali.Jab try this.. `NSString *strUrl = [YOUR_URL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUnicodeStringEncoding];`

Comment: didn't work my friend, the problem is with the hashes (#).

Comment: yes, it will convert # to %FF%FE%23%00 but you said its not worked

Comment: it also didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Might be your string url is containing any spaces or any other special characters that must be encoded. like below

```
 NSString *feedbackUrl = [self.getConfig.feedbackURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];   
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: feedbackUrl]];
```

hope it helps.!!!

Comment: I tired it, but nothing changed

Comment: I tried at my end and I am able to get the url, may be your special character is creating problem

Comment: https://cms.topmerits.com/CRM/feedback#/1715171559ae979371687#/10306 this is the url which I am receiving from the server

Comment: as per [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl/1572047-urlwithstring), "This method expects URLString to contain only characters that are allowed in a properly formed URL. All other characters must be properly percent escaped. Any percent-escaped characters are interpreted using UTF-8 encoding". So I think that needs to be handle at your server side. also it seems like error is at server side at first glance, though I am not that much sure, confirm at your end

Comment: and if its not solved by server side? isn't there any other solution?

Comment: for now I don't have any other solution as NSURL never allows special characters , just give a try from server side once. And let me know if it works

Comment: on server side, they aren't able to change the # , since they are using it as an id.

Comment: I am not that much aware about server scripting, but they might need to consider encoding. as url will be encoded all the time.

Answer (score 1):

This might be happening because of the special characters that must be encoded. The following encoding works for me-

```
NSString *feedbackUrl = [self.getConfig.feedbackURL stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];   
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: feedbackUrl]];
```

Comment: I tried it, "#" in the url changed to "%", so it opened the safari, but giving an error that NOTFoundhttpException.

Comment: https://cms.topmerits.com/CRM/feedback#/1715171559ae979371687#/10306 this is the url which works, after using your method, it became : https://cms.topmerits.com/CRM/feedback%23/1715171559ae979371687%23/10306 and didn't work

Answer (score -1):

This is the code to open the link in browser, Hope this help

```
    - (IBAction)emailButton:(id)sender {

[[UIApplication sharedApplication]
 openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.emailLabel.text]];
    }
```

Comment: Why Un Like Sir.?

Comment: This Web Site not giving Permition


- (IBAction)btn:(id)sender {

    NSString* str= @"https://cms.topmerits.com/CRM/feedback#/1715171559ae979371687#/10306";
    [self openScheme:str];

}
- (void)openScheme:(NSString *)scheme {
    UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:scheme];
    [application openURL:URL options:@{} completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
        if (success) {
            NSLog(@"Opened %@",scheme);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Error %@",scheme);
        }
    }];
}